# Почему при вставке текста из буфера обмена в Richtextbox, текст есть, а свойство пустое?

Tags: wpf

Заметил такую странность, у меня на форме wpf, есть этот элемент, соответственно этот элемент привязан к свойству. если я пишу с клавиатуры текст в этом элементе, то свойство отрабатывает. А если я например скопирую простой текст из любого источника, и потом поставлю курсор в ричтекстбокс, и сделаю вставить, то текст в элементе вижу, а свойство null. Как будто элемент его не увидел. Как это исправить. Вот так  я делаю привязку.

```
 <RichTextBox FontSize="25" Height="189" Margin="43,78,24,0" VerticalAlignment="Top">
                <FlowDocument>
                    <Paragraph>
                        <Run Text="{Binding Request, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
                    </Paragraph>
                </FlowDocument>
            </RichTextBox>
```

Comment: @Kromster поправил

Comment: Покажите как привязываетесь. После перевода фокуса на другой контрол тоже не срабатывает привязка?

Comment: @АндрейNOP Поправил вопрос,добавил xaml.

Comment: Ну дык вы создаете отдельный Run, а при вставке текста вы вставляете не в него уже (его может там вообще уже нет). Придется делать что-то вроде такого: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/882143/218063

Comment: @АндрейNOP Спасибо за ответ, придется делать через поведение